# Kotlin - Order list by category and subcategory

Tags: algorithm, list, kotlin

I have a list of object with a String attribute "Category" and the other String attribute with a String attribute "Subcategory".

I would like to order my list by Category and inside each category order them by Subcategory.

For example I have a list like :

Object1("Category1","Subcategory1"),

Object2("Category2","SubcategoryA"),

Object3("Category1","Subcategory1"),

Object4("Category1","Subcategory2"),

Object5("Category2","SubcategoryB")

I would like to have a list order like: {Object1, Object3, Object4, Object2, Object5}

Is there a simple way to do that in Kotlin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**objectList** - List of Object Type

Sorting this `objectList` by **Category** then by **Subcategory**

```
objectList.sortedWith(compareBy<ObjectType>{ it.Category }.thenBy{ it.Subcategory })
```

Comment: Thank you, It was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this code:

```
yourList.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.Category }, { it.Subcategory }))
```